# How can I create a grouped bar chart with Matplotlib or Seaborn from a multi-indexed data frame?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn, multi-index

I have a problem regarding how I can plot multi-indexed data in a single bar chart. I started with a DataFrame with three columns (artist, genre and miscl_count) and 195 rows. I then grouped the data by two of the columns, which resulted in the table below. My question is, how can I create a bar plot from this, so that the each group in "miscl_count" are shown as three separate bar plots across all five genres (i.e. a total amount of 3x5 bars)? I would also like the genre to identify what color a bar is assigned.

I know that there is unstacking, but I don't understand how I can get this to work with Matplotlib or Seaborn.

The head of the DataFrame, that I perform the groupby method on looks like this:

```
print(miscl_df.head())

          artist     miscl_count      genre
0          band1               5          a
1          band2               6          b
2          band3               5          b
3          band4               4          b
4          band5               5          b
5          band6               5          c

miscl_df_group = miscl_df.groupby(['genre', 'miscl_count']).count()
print(miscl_df_group)
```

After group by, the output looks like this:

```
        artist        
miscl_count       4   5   6
genre                      
a                11   9   9
b                19  13  16
c                13  14  16
d                10   9  12
e                21  14  10
```

Just to make sure I made myself clear, the output should be shown as a single chart (and not as subplots)!

Working solution to be used on the grouped data:

```
miscl_df_group.unstack(level='genre').plot(kind='bar')
```

Alternatively, it can also be used this way:

```
miscl_df_group.unstack(level='miscl_count').plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

with seaborn, no need to group the data, this is done under the hood:

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(x="artist", y="miscl_count", hue="genre", data=miscl_df)
```

(change the column names at will, depending on what you want)

```py
# full working example
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["artist"] = list(map(lambda i: f"band{i}", np.random.randint(1,4,size=(100,))))
df["genre"] = list(map(lambda i: f"genre{i}", np.random.randint(1,6,size=(100,))))
df["count"] = np.random.randint(50,100,size=(100,))

# df
#     count    genre artist
# 0      97   genre9  band1
# 1      95   genre7  band1
# 2      65   genre3  band2
# 3      81   genre1  band1
# 4      58  genre10  band1
# ..    ...      ...    ...
# 95     61   genre1  band2
# 96     53   genre9  band2
# 97     55   genre9  band1
# 98     94   genre1  band2
# 99     85   genre8  band1

# [100 rows x 3 columns]


sns.barplot(x="artist", y="count", hue="genre", data=df)
```

[image: For 3 artists and 5 genres, this is the result...]

Comment: That does not seem to be working for me. To clarify, I added information about the original dataframe (miscl_df) to my original post.

Comment: See the full working example in my answer. You'll see that it works fine... Also, I tried it with strings instead of integers for the artist/genre and it works all the same

Comment: Thanks for the proposition. I somehow managed to do this in one line of code (added this to the original plots), but this one-liner plots the results straight away. I would still like to know how I can chain this with other stuff, so that I can edit the legend and the colors of the bars myself etc.

Comment: you can edit the graph elements like any other matplotlib plot: to get the axes: `ax = plt.gca()` then do what you want with the elements... BTW, the answer I gave is also a one liner...